# NoClassDefFoundError for library project classes ONLY when running tests with ANT

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant, robolectric

I added `ViewPagerIndicator` to my project (it's an Android library project), and my tests work fine from IntelliJ, but fail when I run them from ANT. To be clear, only the test that is referencing classes from this Android Library project is failing, the rest are passing without any issue. I'm guessing something isn't right in my build.xml? Anyone else run into this?

Here's the stack trace:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Lcom/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator;
>   com.google.inject.internal.util.$ComputationException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   Lcom/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator;  at
>   com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:553)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.util.$MapMaker$StrategyImpl.compute(MapMaker.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.util.$CustomConcurrentHashMap$ComputingImpl.get(CustomConcurrentHashMap.java:2041)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:50)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:950)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getMembersInjector(InjectorImpl.java:957)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.injectMembers(InjectorImpl.java:943)
>     at
>   roboguice.inject.ContextScopedRoboInjector.injectMembersWithoutViews(ContextScopedRoboInjector.java:243)
>     at roboguice.activity.RoboActivity.onCreate(RoboActivity.java:78)   at
>   com.mycompany.myproduct.activities.TutorialActivity.onCreate(TutorialActivity.java:36)
>     at
>   com.mycompany.myproduct.activities.TutorialActivityTest.setup(TutorialActivityTest.java:37)
>     at
>   com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)

Comment: Add `android.library.reference.1="path to lib folder"` in ant.properties file.

Comment: @Tarun I already have that defined in my project.properties file.

Comment: @Tarun That works fine if you aren't doing automated builds. And you shouldn't be adding the library references yourself, that's what 'android update project' is for.

Comment: But android update project doesn't update ant.properties. Do you mean if I dont add lib ref in ant file the project would still compile successfully?

Comment: android update project will add library references to your project.properties file, there's no need to add them manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.

In the `junit` task under the `test` target in **build.xml** (I took the snippet from the [AndroidIntellijStarter](https://github.com/pivotal/AndroidIntelliJStarter/blob/master/build.xml) project on Github), you need to add a `classpath` reference pointing to the **classes.jar** file that gets built for every library project you have included in your project.

There might be a more elegant way to achieve this, but it's what I came up with on short notice:

```
<target name="test" depends="compile.tests" description="test all">
        <mkdir dir="${out.dir}/out/reports/tests"/>
        <junit showoutput="true" failureproperty="junit.failure">
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" if="junit.console.out"/>
            <formatter type="plain"/>
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <batchtest todir="${out.dir}/out/reports/tests">
                <fileset dir="${tested.project.test.absolute.dir}">
                    <include name="**/*Test.java"/>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
            <classpath>
                <!-- Project -->
                <pathelement path="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"/>
                <pathelement path="${out.test.classes.absolute.dir}"/>
                <fileset dir="${extensible.libs.classpath}" includes="**/*.jar"/>

                <!-- Library Project Here -->
                <fileset dir="path/to/classes/jar" includes="*.jar"/>

                <!-- Robolectric -->
                <fileset dir="submodules/robolectric/lib/main" includes="*.jar"/>
                <pathelement path="submodules/robolectric/bin/mainClasses"/>

                <!-- Android -->
                <path refid="android.target.classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </junit>
        <fail if="junit.failure" message="Unit test(s) failed.  See reports!"/>
</target>
```